# UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't fire up on UIView Subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I've created a custom subclass of UIView because I needed to override drawRect method.
I try to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to it, but this doesn't work for me.
Here, the code of my ViewController:

```
MyCustomView *customView = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectFrame(0, 30, 30, 30)];
[customView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething)];
[customView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

I don't understand why when I touch my UIView subclass object, the gesture recognizer doesn't fire up.

Thanks a lot in advance !

**FIXED IT OUT !**

My view was on a UIImageView, and that UIImageView hadn't the `userInteractionEnabled` set to YES.

Comment: is your bounds/frame correct?

Comment: Apparently yes, my sublass is in fact a circle drawn with CoreGraphics. the frame is: 10, 30, 30, 30.

Comment: For information (it may help), the code I show you is in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method. One idea ?

Comment: in this case it would be better, if you declare your customView as an UIControl and not as an UIView and remove the UITapGestureRecognizer and add a target (like adding a target to an UIButton) to your CustomView

Comment: I tried with UIControl, it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**FIXED IT OUT !**

My view was on a UIImageView, and that UIImageView hadn't the `userInteractionEnabled` set to YES.

Comment: This helped me even 3 years later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are displaying it somewhere (`addSubview`).

Comment: Yes I display my view. I make an addSubview method after the add of the gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that userInteractionEnabled is set to true. If that's true, post the code that creates and hooks up the gesture recognizer.

Comment: userInteractionEnabled is set to true. I posted the code in my first code just on top of the topic. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set the UserInteractionEnable check to true on the subview that you are adding and in the selector method, do pass the object along with it i.e.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];
```

and make the selector method as

```
-(void) doSomething:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture;
```

Let me know if you are still having an issue.
Thanks!

Comment: It was just that the UIImageView in which I add my subview wasn't userInteractionEnabled... Fixed, thanks !

Comment: That is great. Now dont forget to leave the post unanswered or unmarked.
Cheers!